# Restricting search based on a particular country in the Google Maps Places API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Maps' Places API for autocompletion of location as user types. But how can I restrict the suggestions to a particular country?

Here is my javascript:

```
function initAutocomplete() {

    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete-input');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

    // [START region_getplaces]
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
    // more details for that place.
    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
        if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fixed it by changing SearchBox to Autocomplete and passing an options with the requirements..Here is the code if someone needs.

```
function initAutocomplete() {

    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete-input');
    var options = {
        componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}
    };

    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

    // [START region_getplaces]
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
    // more details for that place.
    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
        if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: With replacing `.SearchBox` with `.Autocomplete` the autocomplete is working fine, but `'places_changed'` not triggered when user choose a place or hit enter.

Comment: Posted what I found as an answer.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam I dont think I had the issue you mentioned(maybe there is an api change as i implemented a while back). I cant recall properly as this is a while back. My current application uses autocomplete with country restriction and working fine. I will recheck and get back as am not sure about the approach I took this time.

Comment: Good point about the API change. I'm using Maps API v3 (`3.30.13`).

Comment: I also have same problem

Comment: According to the documentation [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#Autocomplete.place_changed) the event name should be 'place_changed' when binding to autocomplete. So replacing 'places_changed' to 'place_changed' should work.

Comment: I have the same issue about the event binding not working. Thanks zeee for the solution, change event from places_changed to place_changed work for me. Please also take note that the function to get place is getPlace() instead of getPlaces()

Answer (score 13):

**Note:** I'm using Google Maps API v3 (v3.30.13)

@Abhilash's approach to the problem was nice to try with. But with his answer, I faced a problem: the autocomplete was working fine, but it didn't triggering the `places_changed` method. And there's no console error too.

Then with [the answer by @geocodezip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32193158/1743124) in another thread, I figured out that, the event fired up with `Autocomplete` is not `places_changed`, but [`place_changed`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete) (note the difference of **singular form**).

And there are other changes required if you want to proceed with `place_changed`, because with `place_changed` it return only a single place, not an array of places. So:

- instead of `.getPlaces()` you have to use `.getPlace()`
- instead of `places.forEach(function(place) { ... }` you have to work with `place` directly.

  ```
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var restrictOptions = {
      componentRestrictions: {country: 'bd'}
  };
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, restrictOptions);

  searchBox.addListener('place_changed', function() {

      var place = searchBox.getPlace();

      if (place.length == 0) {
          return;
      }

      if (!place.geometry) {
          console.log("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
          return;
      }

      // ...

  });
  ```

#### Caveat

The limitation is: with `.SearchBox()` google places search work even with random string, but with `.Autocomplete()` random string cannot find out any `.geometry`, hence cannot pinpoint to any matched area on the map. With `.SearchBox()` if you type "Name of a place", hit enter, it can point to *Placename, Locality*. But with `.Autocomplete()` without choosing from the autosuggestion[s] it cannot trigger the place's `.geometry`. The following `console.log(place)` displays the difference between random string and autocomplete chosen item:

[image: Random place vs. autocomplete place]

#### Aftermath

I's not satisfied with the outcome how `.Autocomplete()` worked for me. So until having a nicer solution, I decided to stick to the `.SearchBox()` method - though it's not restricting the search suggestions. But binding with `bounds_changed` it binds the search result a little bit, though it's not strict and satisfactory, but at least something's better than nothing. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

```
// Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
front_end_map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(front_end_map.getBounds());
});
```

I, desperately am, looking forward for a bulletproof solution...

Comment: i am getting an error searchBox.getPlace is not a function

Comment: I also have same issue , the autocomplete was working fine, but it didn't triggering the places_changed method. And there's no console error too

Comment: +1, helps a lot. However, maybe it's since changed, but autocomplete now returns geometry. Will snap to a location on the map when you select a location. The caveat for me is that when you search a generic term, the SearchBox will create a pin for the top results but the autocomplete won't, since it expects a selected place not a vague term.

Comment: @Ryan Please that it helped. What about adding another answer with the updates that you got with the new API? Somebody else will get help from that too.