# How to write a validation to select the item only from the dropdown in google places auto complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, google-places-api

I have used google places autocomplete API in an input field.

Now, I want to write a validation to select only the items in the dropdown.

I want to avoid free form text.

Please look at the code that I have written below:

```
<input ng-disabled="disableForm" class="form-control" ng-model="city"
 g-places-autocomplete autocomplete="off" options="autocompleteOptions" 
force-selection="true" id="city"  name="city" placeholder="City" type="text">
```

Comment: can you add jsfiddle link into question?

Comment: Sure will do that.

Comment: this appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14652507/4481226